# ¿Cómo eliminar vocales con tildes en php?

Tags: php

Mi código es este

```
<head>
    <title>ORACION</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="generator" content="Geany 1.30.1"/>
</head>
<?php
    $v1=$_POST['frase'];
    $v1= strtoupper($v1); //Transforma todo en mayúscula

    echo "LA FRASE A ESTUDIAR ES: <br> <br>";
    echo $v1."<br>";

    for ($i=0; $i<strlen($v1); $i++)
        if(($v1[$i]=='A')||($v1[$i]=='E')||($v1[$i]=='I')||($v1[$i]=='O')||($v1[$i]=='U')||($v1[$i]=='í')||($v1[$i]=='Í'))
            $v1[$i]=' ';

    echo "LA FRSE SIN VOCALES ES: <br> <br>";
    echo $v1."<br><br>";

    echo "<a href='Semana2-4.html'>VOLVER</a>";
?>
```

Comment: [Esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3373364/5587982) usa un array que abarca todas las posibilidades de vocales acentuadas, reemplazándolas por su correspondiente sin acento.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes usar el array elaborado por @Lizard [en esta respuesta de SO en Inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3373364/5587982).

Adaptado a tu código sería simplemente esto:

```
<head>
    <title>ORACION</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="generator" content="Geany 1.30.1"/>
</head>
<?php
    $v1=$_POST['frase'];
    $v1= strtoupper($v1); //Transforma todo en mayúscula

    echo "LA FRASE A ESTUDIAR ES: <br> <br>";
    echo $v1."<br>";

    $unwanted_array = array(    'Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A', 'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E',
                                'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I', 'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O', 'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U',
                                'Ú'=>'U', 'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss', 'à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a', 'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c',
                                'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e', 'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i', 'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o', 'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o',
                                'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u', 'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b', 'ÿ'=>'y' );

    $v1 = strtr( $v1, $unwanted_array );

    echo "LA FRSE SIN VOCALES ES: <br> <br>";
    echo $v1."<br><br>";
    echo "<a href='Semana2-4.html'>VOLVER</a>";
?>
```

Si no quieres usar tantas posibilidades de reemplazo, puedes modificar el array. Esto es tá pensando para diferentes idiomas.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar simplemente [iconv](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.iconv.php):

```
echo iconv( 'UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', 'Yá sí está la yegüa libre' );

// Salida: Ya si esta la yegua libre
```

> Si se añade el string //TRANSLIT a out_charset, se activa la transliteración. Esto significa que cuando un caracter no puede ser representado en el set de caracteres final, se puede aproximar a uno o varios caracteres parecidos.

<kbd>[Ver demo online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2049d50203b5f56c94f3adf9bfb8f09c06f78629)</kbd>