# ¿Cómo detectar si una URL está codificada en PHP?

Tags: php, regex, php5

**Introducción:**

Tengo un script que hace peticiones a URLS, pero algunas están codificadas y otras no. Existen algunas URLS que no están codificadas y tienen acentos á,í,ú y esas debería codificarlas antes de hacer la petición.

He buscado y parece que no existe ninguna función oficial para detectar si una URL se encuentra codificada o no.

**Documentación leída:**

Basándome en la primer respuesta a está [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564837/how-to-know-if-a-url-is-decoded-encoded?rq=1#comment25553830_17564837) puede hacer el siguiente código:

**Código actual:**

```
            if(!preg_match("/%[0-9a-f]{2}/i", $url["_id"]))
                $url["_id"] = urlencode($url["_id"]);
```

**Problemas/Preguntas:**

Si uso `urlencode()` o `rawurlencode()` la url me queda "destruida", de tal forma que al hacer la petición con `get_file_contents()` me da error de URL no válida.

Creo que es porque me dejan así la URL (sólo muestro el principio):

```
https%3A%2F%2F
```

¿Cómo puedo detectar si una URL necesita ser codifica? ¿Cómo codificar esa URL correctamente?

Comment: Con esto: `$url='http://hola.com/"cómillas_id?asdasdasdá"';

if(!preg_match("/%[0-9a-f]{2}/i", $url["_id"])){
                $url["_id"] = urlencode($url["_id"]);}
                
                echo $url;` no me ha funcionado, y si quito lo de ["_id"] me convierte la url entera, lo cual no te interesa.

Comment: $url es un array, en mi caso la key "_id" es donde se encuentra la URL. Tu definiste una variable...

Comment: Ahhh leches, ya decía. Igualmente si en la key id tienes una url completa no te va a servir. Siguiendo el ejemplo de antes mira lo que sale con una url entera: "http%3A%2F%2Fhola.com%2F%22c%C3%B3millas_id%3Fasdasdasd%C3%A1%22" Convierte todo, incluidos los caracteres válidos. El navegador lo lee, pero no es correcto.

Comment: Efectivamente, acabo de añadir el problema a la pregunta inicial. Tanto urlencode() como rawurlencode() me retornan una URL que no es válida para posteriormente realizar la petición con get_file_contents() ¿alguna sugerencia sobre como detectar si es necesario o no codificar una URL? y ¿cómo codificarla correctamente?

Comment: Pues mira, en el manual de php el primer usuario responde a este problema y sugiere un cambio. http://php.net/manual/es/function.urlencode.php monta dos arrays, los recorre y reemplaza lo que no cuadre en tu string con lo del array segundo. Echale un ojo que lo mismo te es util. la respuesta me sale justo debajo de la explicación y el usuario es: davis dot peixoto at gmail dot com

Comment: Pero es que no entiendo, ¿cómo es posible que se produzcan URLs con acentos? ¿de dónde se producen dichas URLs así? ¿acaso no está ahí el origen del problema, en permitir que eso ocurra? O sea, es como dejar que tu casa se incendie para luego apagar el fuego. ¿Sería acaso lógico hacer eso, por qué mejor no evitas el incendio tomando las precauciones de lugar?

Comment: @Emerita en el Manual de PHP se puede enlazar directamente a cualquier nota de contribución. Si haces clic sobre el nombre del usuario, en la barra del navegador tendrás algo como esto: `http://php.net/manual/es/function.urlencode.php#97969` y lo puedes usar para [referir directamente al comentario](http://php.net/manual/es/function.urlencode.php#97969).

Comment: @A.Cedano básicamente porque el incendio no lo provoco yo, simplemente tengo las urls y debo hacer peticiones. ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: Entonces ¿quién provoca el incendio, o sea, de dónde vienen las URLs? ¿El problema son sólo las palabras acentuadas o hay más irregularidades en esos datos? A mi me parece extraño que algún programador haya hecho un código tan descabellado que permita escribir URLs con acentos o con dibujitos o cosas así  ¿?

Comment: @A.Cedano No sabia lo de la referencia del manual. Muchas gracias. En cuanto a este caso, yo he estado trabajando en sitios donde haciamos harvestings de OAI's en los que las urls estaban hechas polvo, hasta con espacios, y me tocaba adecentar esas urls. A veces con PHP otras con BASH, según la cantidad y dificultad. Lo mismo se lo han pasado y no hay manera de que lo hagan decentemente, o es algo antiguo y han pedido reutilizarlo.

Comment: @Emerita yo creo que en la pregunta faltan datos sobre el contexto para poder ayudar mejor al OP. Y la primera pregunta es precisamente de dónde vienen los datos y por qué vienen así. Luego se podría determinar exactamente cuál es el alcance del problema: URLs sólo con acentos, URLs con cualquier cosa: acentos, caritas, símbolos, etc y luego entonces establecer un plan de saneamiento en base a lo que se tiene. Pero primero hay que ver de dónde viene el problema para corregirlo de raíz. Imagina que es algo activo y que se sigue permitiendo que se reproduzca el error al infinito.

Comment: @A.Cedano Las urls vienen de sitemaps de sitios, mi idea es hacer algo que funcione para casi todos los casos (99%), es decir, una función que determine si es necesario o no codificar. En caso de que sea necesario, pues se codificará de tal forma que el get_file_contents() no falle. Estoy haciendo pruebas de la función que estaba en ese enlace que me enviaron, creado por un usuario.

Comment: @A.Cedano Totalmente de acuerdo. Si es un proceso automatizado hay que saber que está haciendo y cual es la casuistica de las URL's. Quiero suponer que el OP ha analizado la casuistica del problema y por eso pregunta solo para los acentos y no para mas cosas. Pero si estaría bien una confirmación o muestras.

Comment: Carlos, si como dice @Emerita el problema son solamente los acentos, por qué no aplicas una función de reemplazo sobre las palabras acentuadas ([algo como esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/238401/29967) y dado que es una URL podrías usar  `strtolower` si fuera necesario). Se trata de usar `$unwanted_array` para reemplazar cualquier caracter acentuado. Y, si hubiera otros símbolos no deseados, lo pones en ese array con la letra por la que debería ser reemplazado.

Comment: He probado con un caso que no me funcionaba y ha ido OK. ¿Sirve para todas las Urls o debo hacer un chequeo previo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No queda claro si la url está dentro de un scalar o un array, en cualquier caso, una vez defines una función para que trate esa url, da igual mientras se lo pases como parámetro. Prueba con lo siguiente: (la idea es utilizar urlencode y luego restaurar los caracteres válidos según el estandard RFC 3986 para URIs)

```
<?php

function miUrlEncode($string) {
    // Basado en http://php.net/manual/es/function.urlencode.php#97969

    if (preg_match("/%[0-9a-f]{2}/i", $string)) {
        return $string;
    }

    $entities = array('%21', '%2A', '%27', '%28', '%29', '%3B', '%3A', '%40', '%26', '%3D', '%2B', '%24', '%2C', '%2F', '%3F', '%25', '%23', '%5B', '%5D');
    $replacements = array('!', '*', "'", "(", ")", ";", ":", "@", "&", "=", "+", "$", ",", "/", "?", "%", "#", "[", "]");
    return str_replace($entities, $replacements, urlencode($string));
}

$mi_url_codificada    = 'https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245279/c%c3%b3mo-detectar-si-una-url-est%c3%a1-codificada-en-php';
$mi_url_sin_codificar = 'https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245279/cómo-detectar-si-una-url-está-codificada-en-php';

$array_con_urls['url_codificada']    = 'https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245279/c%c3%b3mo-detectar-si-una-url-est%c3%a1-codificada-en-php';
$array_con_urls['url_sin_codificar'] = 'https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245279/cómo-detectar-si-una-url-está-codificada-en-php';

print(miUrlEncode($mi_url_codificada) . "\n");
print(miUrlEncode($mi_url_sin_codificar) . "\n");

print(miUrlEncode($array_con_urls['url_codificada']) . "\n");
print(miUrlEncode($array_con_urls['url_sin_codificar']) . "\n");
```

Tienes una demo [aquí](https://www.ideone.com/nkMolY)

Si pudieras encontrar URLs que tuvieran trozos codificados y otros sin codificar, podrías utilizar esta alternativa:

```
<?php

function miUrlEncode($string) {
    if (preg_match("/%[0-9a-f]{2}/i", $string)) {
        // Parece codificada, codificamos por trozos
        $trozos = preg_split("/(%[0-9a-f]{2})/i", $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
        $trozos_tratados = array_map(function ($trozo) {
            return preg_match("/^%[0-9a-f]{2}$/i", $trozo)
              ? $trozo
              : miStrEncode($trozo);
        }, $trozos);
        return implode('', $trozos_tratados);
    }
    // No parece codificada, la codificamos entera
    return miStrEncode($string);
}

function miStrEncode($string) {
    $entities = array('%21', '%2A', '%27', '%28', '%29', '%3B', '%3A', '%40', '%26', '%3D', '%2B', '%24', '%2C', '%2F', '%3F', '%25', '%23', '%5B', '%5D');
    $replacements = array('!', '*', "'", "(", ")", ";", ":", "@", "&", "=", "+", "$", ",", "/", "?", "%", "#", "[", "]");
    return str_replace($entities, $replacements, urlencode($string));
}

$mi_url_codificada    = 'https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245279/c%c3%b3mo-detectar-si-una-url-est%c3%a1-codificada-en-php';
$mi_url_sin_codificar = 'https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245279/cómo-detectar-si-una-url-está-codificada-en-php';

$array_con_urls['url_codificada']    = 'https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245279/c%c3%b3mo-detectar-si-una-url-est%c3%a1-codificada-en-php';
$array_con_urls['url_sin_codificar'] = 'https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245279/cómo-detectar-si-una-url-está-codificada-en-php';

print(miUrlEncode($mi_url_codificada) . "\n");
print(miUrlEncode($mi_url_sin_codificar) . "\n");

print(miUrlEncode($array_con_urls['url_codificada']) . "\n");
print(miUrlEncode($array_con_urls['url_sin_codificar']) . "\n");


print(miUrlEncode('www.foo.bar/españa/%AD/sí%12/') . "\n");
```

La idea es mirar si una url parece codificada. Si es el caso, dividiremos la url en trozos. Los trozos que parecen codificados los dejaremos tal cual e iremos codificando los otros.

Tienes una demo de esta nueva versión [aquí](https://www.ideone.com/dnIgOD)

Comment: ¿La condición (if) sirve para determinar, al menos, el 99% de los casos si la url está o no codificada?

Comment: Sí, debería. Básicamente mira si existe un `%` seguido de dos caracteres que son números o letras de la `a` a la `f`. Es decir, 1 byte en hexadecimal. Debería ser condición adecuada para detectar urls codificadas. Aún así, una manera de que 'fallase' es que la url en cuestión tuviese trozos codificados y otros trozos que no. Por ejemplo algo así: `www.foo.bar/españa/%0d`. En tal caso la dejaría tal cual. Entiendo que esto no debería ser algo común... pero si detectas que es el caso, aún se podría mejorar algo más

Comment: @Carlos. He añadido a mi respuesta una nueva versión del código que solucionaría el posible problema de urls con mezcla de partes codificadas y partes sin codificar. Con esto entiendo que ya debería ser 100% fiable :-)

Comment: muchas gracias :) ya te contaré